# Как передать значение переменной на другое устройство в android

Tags: android, переменные, wifi, передача-данных

Всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как передать значение переменной на другое устройство. Думал использовать wifi direct. Но как это реализовать? Буду благодарен.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.